# Remote access Mikrotik with no public IP

Tags: ip, remote, mikrotik

I have a Mikrotik behind a broadband router, I want to access the Mikrotik using web or winbox but the problems are;

1- Mikrotik could access internet but has no public IP

2- Using VPN is forbidden here

3-Broadband router is not physical accessible and no port forwarding allowed

is there any solution like reverse SSH or something like or using ip cloud to access the Mikrotik via a VPS(Linux or Windows)?

Please Please help me, I'm in a bad situation

Comment: Allowing router access for configurations from the outside is actually putting out a sign asking to be hacked.

Answer (score 1):

You can not, simple like that. It is likely that even IF you manage - which I am not sure you could - the result would be you getting fired because of you going around the business internet policy.

The problem is that you have no public IP at all and VPN is not allowed, and NAT is not - that rules out all possible ways to communicate via IP, which the internet needs.

This smells brutally like a business or internet provider telling you that internet is NOT for publishing anything - and bypassing this is not a technical question. Besides being off topic, you open yourself to criminal prosecution and immediate job loss. Do not do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an outgoing SSTP tunnel which works using SSL/TLS over port 443 (so it shouldn't be blocked) to connect to another SSTP server outside the network.

Then you can access the router with the IP assigned on the SSTP interface.

Comment: Thanx let me try it

Comment: SSTP is "a form of a VPN" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Socket_Tunneling_Protocol

Comment: If "VPN is forbidden" is a technical issue, this works. If it's a policy issue, [policy circumventing is off-topic](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2497/should-we-modify-the-faq-to-include-policy-subversion-as-explicitly-off-topic).

Answer (score -3):

Create NAT rules from the broadmabd router (if you have access) to forward incoming connections on port 8291 (for example) to your Mikrotik's LAN address.

Comment: OP mentioned that port forwarding is not an option.